# SPARQL BIND(COUNT(...) AS ...) not working

Tags: sparql, blazegraph

I'm trying to assign a count to a variable for later use in the query (SPARQL).

I can't even get the following to work:

```
SELECT ?resultsCount
WHERE{
    ?subject ?predicate ?object.
    BIND(COUNT(?object) AS ?resultsCount)
}
```

There is something wrong with my syntax or semantics here, as I simply get an empty result repeated `?resultsCount` many times, instead of simply e.g. 86 (number of results).

However, I get the number of results (e.g. 86) when I do the following:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?object) AS ?resultsCount)
WHERE{
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
```

Is there any way to get `BIND` to work with `COUNT` like in the first example? If not, is there a different correct way to get the same sort of functionality?

I'm using Blazegraph 2.1.2. Could it be a bug with that?

Answer (score 2):

**count** is an aggregate function.  To use **count**, you need to use **group by** in your query, and use **count** in the projection.  **Count** will count the number of results *within each group*.  You can also use **distinct** with **count**, so you could do something like the following to get the number of distinct objects for each subject:

```
select ?subject (count(?object) as ?numObjects) {
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
group by ?subject
```

If you're just trying to count the number of matches, then you can use **count** without a **group by** (which gives you a single, implicit, group):

```
select (count(*) as ?numResults) {
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
```